# toString method of Calendar returns inconsistent data

Tags: java

The test below has two identical checks. The first one succeeds, but the last one doesn't.

I know how to work around the problem, but I'm guessing there is a bug in the method `toString`.

```
    // Calendar calendar = new Calendar.Builder().setDate(2024, Calendar.JANUARY, 25).build();
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(2024, Calendar.JANUARY, 25);
    assertThat(calendar.toString(), not(containsString("DAY_OF_YEAR=25"))); // success
    assertEquals(25, calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR)); // success
    assertThat(calendar.toString(), not(containsString("DAY_OF_YEAR=25"))); // fail
```

Comment: Lots of `Calendar` methods have side effects, so this isn't particularly surprising. Lesson of the day: don't use `Calendar`.

Comment: What is [your goal](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/15-smart-questions)?

Comment: Check out the java.time package for date and time requirements.

Comment: When time is not set, `calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR)` will update the time apparently... You can debug and see yourself. 

Use LocalDate, Calendar is outdated!

Comment: The side effects are very unpleasant, but it looks like I'll have to deal with them. I got legacy with org.eclipse.persistence entities

Comment: [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html#toString()) of `toString()`: "*... This method is intended to be used only for debugging purposes, and the format of the returned string may vary between implementations. ...*" || why do you think that is a bug? `get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR)` is calculating the day of year and probably *caching* it for later re-use; `toString()` is printing out all known (cached/calculated) fields

Comment: more, [`get()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html#get(int)): "*... The normalization and validation are handled by the `complete()` method ...*" and [`complete()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html#complete()): "*Fills in any unset fields in the calendar fields. ...*" || so calling `get()` ends up filling any unset fields, which then will also be included in the result of `toString()` || and don't forget this is a class which uses `2` for March and `11` for December, don't expect too much!

Comment: `java.time.LocalDate.of( 2024 , Month.JANUARY , 25 ).getDayOfYear()` Never use `Calendar`, terribly flawed.